# Titanium Appcelerator Code Minify

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, minify, recover

While I was using titanium, my code was minified.
How do I recover minified javascript code files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your editor you can do it (auto indent) there straight away (if you have just minimized it):

- Appclerator Studio: `Ctrl+Shift+F` on Windows or `Cmd+Shift+F` on Mac
- Atom: with Atom Beautify (https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) Ctrl+Alt+B

Comment: Yes this is success for code alignment. But did not recover my variable names. How can i recover variable names?

Comment: you can't.  This part is called `obfuscating` and is there to make your code "unreadable" and can't be recovered because the mapping is not stored. It should still work because it's valid code but you are stuck with the new variable names etc.